# How to debug a Lua script in Sublime Text 2 under Linux

Tags: scripting, lua, sublimetext2

I am using Lua (I am newbie on it) for scripting under Sublime Text 2 and Linux and I would like to debug my script so I would like to set some breakpoints. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime text 2 is just a text editor, it is not an environment and so you cannot debug in it.  I don't actually script Lua, so I am not that familiar with the tools available for it but they [are out there](http://lua-users.org/wiki/DebuggingLuaCode).

Comment: Thanks for the link. The reason of using Lua as scritping if because I am trying to program a video game using corona sdk and I was looking for an IDE that integrates corona sdk and lua.

Comment: You may want to try [ZeroBrane Studio](http://studio.zerobrane.com), which is a Lua IDE that integrates with Corona and provides advanced debugging functionality (I'm the author of the IDE). There is also Glider and CodeHelper that support debugging for Corona applications.

Answer (score 1):

Corona Labs released plugin for Sublime, which supports debugging. Check out: https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Corona%20Editor

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see - no such a thing thing for Sublime Text. Only some kind of Corona Texmate Bundle[1] derivative for Sublime[2].

Also there are couple of links for Corona SDK IDEs in official Corona page[3]. Some of them provides debugging functionality...

[1]http://www.ludicroussoftware.com/corona-textmate-bundle/

[2]https://github.com/drowne/Corona-Sublime

[3]http://www.coronalabs.com/resources/3rd-party-tools-and-services/

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to write a plugin for SLT2/3

Plugins are written in Python, so there is no compilation needed or anything like that. But it's still a huge effort due to the fact that there is virtually no documentation available for the SLT scripting API.

Your best bet would be to borrow from existing projects like

- https://github.com/Kindari/SublimeXdebug
- http://sokolovstas.github.io/SublimeWebInspector/

There is also [Outlaw](http://outlawgametools.com/) which claims to be an IDE but it does not seem to support debugging and is more like a project manager with a mediocre editor attached. You can probably do the same in SLT with a few commandlets. It does seem to have completion though.